# Javascript - get text between <li> by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write some javascript that will grab the inner text of li elements (1-16) and put them into hidden fields.

```
   var myValue9 = document.getElementById("fileName9").value;
   oForm.elements["fileName9"].value = myValue9;


 <input name="fileName9" type="hidden" id="fileName9" />

<li id="wavName9"> Some Text </li>
```

How do I return the text in between the `<li>` and put into the hidden field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("fileName9").value = document.getElementById("wavName9").innerText;
```

You could, in this case, also use innerHTML but that would also give you the HTML the element contains.

Comment: I don't think innerText is supported on Firefox - you would have to use textContent instead on Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

LI tags don't have a `.value` property.  Using plain javascript, you could do it this way:

```
oForm.elements["fileName9"].value = document.getElementById("wavName9").innerHTML;
```

Or, to do all of them from 1 to 16, you could use this loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
    oForm.elements["fileName" + i].value = document.getElementById("wavName" + i).innerHTML;
}
```

Or since you also tagged your post for jQuery, using jQuery you could do it like this:

```
$("#fileName9").val($("#wavName9").text());
```

Or, to do all of them from 1 to 16:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
    $("#fileName" + i).val($("#wavName" + i).text());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to do it.

```
var myvar = $("#wavName9").html()
```

Comment: Adding an entire framework to solve a single JavaScript problem probably isn't the right solution.

Comment: @JimSchubert: The OP tagged the question with "jquery", so Rob isn't adding anything.

Comment: @mblase75 agreed, but looking at the post, it's obvious the OP isn't using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#fileName9').val($('#wavName9').text());
```

Note that you can change `.text()` to .`html()` to return the HTML structure rather than just the text.

You could automate this for multiple `<li>`'s like so:

```
$('li[id^="wavName"]').each(function () {
    var number = this.id.replace('waveName', '');
    $('#fileName' + number).val($(this).text());
});
```

This selects all `<li>`'s who's id starts with "wavName" and stores the text within the `<li>` tag in the hidden input who's id starts with "fileName" and ends with the same integer as the `<li>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do in for all li's

```
$("li[id^=wavName]").each(function(){
var $this = $(this);
$this.closest("input[id^=fileName]").val($this.text())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your li's with id's following such a structure: listitem-n, where n is 1-16 and input fields following the same structure hiddeninputs-n (n = 1-16)

using jfriend00's code, add it in a loop that will traverse 16 times, incrementing a count variable that you will use to transfer the data from list items to hidden inputs

```
var count = 0;
for( i=0; i < 16; i++){
  count ++;

  $("form #hiddeninput-"+count).val($("#listitem-"+count).text());

}
```

Better validate the code, but there's the general idea.

You could also create the hidden fields in javascript from scratch, which would make the code abit more stable IMO as there's less chances of a hidden field missing in the form when the js is executed.